# Launch a Python script upon startup and show the output in a terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, autostart

I am new to Python and working with a Raspberry Pi, and I have encountered what might appear to be a simple question, but it has proven to be quite challenging for me as a beginner. Despite my research, I haven't been able to find a suitable solution yet.

My goal is to have a Python script run automatically upon startup of the Raspberry Pi. However, I also want to view the script's output in a terminal window.

I placed a .desktop file in the directory /home/pi/.config/autostart, it contains the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=autostartProgram
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/autostart.py
Terminal=true
```

I know it's working because I hear the relay click, indicating that my GPIO output is functioning. Additionally, I see the red light on my USB camera, confirming that the Python script is accessing the camera. Everything seems to be working except that the terminal isn't opening, preventing me from seeing the output of my script. :(

It may be important, I'm running the Raspberry OS 64-bit Legacy version on a Raspberry Pi 4B with 8GB RAM; and the Pi automatically loads to desktop without the need of a user to enter a password.

Comment: Programs run at startup don't normally run in Terminals because 1) you normally can't show a Terminal until a user has logged in, and 2) because the system doesn't know who is going to log in, so who the Terminal will belong to. So startup jobs normally write to logfiles that you can read/follow with `journalctl`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Does this also apply if I have auto login enabled? Because the Pi automatically loads into the desktop, and then I hear the clicking noises from the relay and see the red light of the camera.

Comment: I'm not saying you cannot have a Terminal - I am just saying programs don't *tend* to do that. Another reason is that servers are often in *"lights out"* server rooms so nobody can see Terminal windows (in fact they rarely even have screens) but administrators can login via `ssh` and read logs remotely.

Comment: Maybe your Terminal is running but it completes so fast you don't see it. You could try reading a text string from the user before it ends so it stays on screen till you enter something.

Comment: The script iterates through an image classification model in a loop. I need the program to operate without waiting for user input, mostly because there won't be a keyboard connected. There's a high possibility that someone wants to connect a monitor to the Pi to see the confidence levels from the image classification model. I'm open to any method to achieve this. Do you have any ideas on how I can implement it? @MarkSetchell (Thanks for the response, by the way! I honestly didn't expect anyone to notice my question here.)

Comment: Maybe you could save the images to disk so interested parties can `ssh` in and see them? Or save them to a NAS or *share* that users can see? Or maybe use a simple *pub/sub* such as **mosquitto** (MQTT) or **Redis** to publish the images and interested parties could subscribe to that channel.

Comment: Or push on an adorable little $20 DisplayHAT mini which also has 4 pushbuttons https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/display-hat-mini

Comment: OP claims that the Pi already logs into a graphical session on its own. there must surely a way to run the command with a visible terminal, automatically, after graphical login. that question is asked at least once every day by someone using a raspberry pi. they already have solutions for that, I'm sure. the only mistake in this question was to tag "opencv" because that's totally irrelevant to how graphical sessions on linux work.